# Batch that runs a timer in the background. How?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, timer, multitasking

I was wondering if theres a way to make a batch file that uses a timer script (such as the TIMEOUT command) and while the timer is running, make the batch file do other processes. But when the timer runs out, then exit. (Or carry out another small process) I know this means that te batch file would have to run multiple processes at once, i just want to know if its possible somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **start /b cmd /c myTimeout.bat**
This starts a new application in the same window (start /?)

With this mechanism you should be able do multiple jobs at the same time

**EDIT**
For a simple timeout this seems to be a bit oversized.
For a timeout of 6 seconds you can use something like

```
set startTime=%time%
call :timeToMs startMs startTime
set /a timeoutAt=startMs + 6000
:loop
... wait for something, like a file is created, or a CD is inserted
if job_is_ready goto :leaveTheLoop
REM Test if the timeout is reached
set currentTime=%time%
call :timeToMs nowMs currentTime
if nowMs GTR timeoutAt goto :leaveTheLoop
goto :loop

:leaveTheLoop
```

It fits better for real parallel jobs, like a display job and a key-input job for a game.

Comment: start will open a new (commandline) window, it will not start the application "in" the current window. But I agree that it is the only way to start something in the background - at least in Windows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: start with /b starts in the same window

Comment: ok thanks, so how would i make the program goto another section of the script upon completion of the timer? (examples?)

Answer (score 0):

modified the code from jeb so that it works:

```
@echo off
set /A startMs=10*%time:~9,2%+1000*%time:~6,2%+60000*%time:~3,2%+3600000*%time:~0,2%
REM the 6000 in the next line is how many milliseconds of a delay you want
set /a timeoutAt=%startMs%+6000
:loop
REM 'passive' code here:

REM Test if the timeout is reached
2>NUL set /A nowMs=10*%time:~9,2%+1000*%time:~6,2%+60000*%time:~3,2%+3600000*%time:~0,2%
if /I %nowMs% GTR %timeoutAt% goto leaveTheLoop
goto loop

:leaveTheLoop
REM do the things you want to do when the timer ends
```