# Batch - Countup Timer

Tags: batch-file, timer

I'm trying to make a countup timer in batch and so far, I have this

```
:timer
set time=0
:time
set /a time=%time%+1
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto time
```

The problem is, I want this to run at the same time another event is happening in the same batch file. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch that runs a timer in the background. How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340883/batch-that-runs-a-timer-in-the-background-how)

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to time how long it takes to execute your batch script?  If you have PowerShell installed you can use the `Measure-Command` cmdlet.

Save this as `timeit.bat`:

```
@echo off
>~timeit-%~n1.bat echo(%*
powershell "Measure-Command {Start-Process ~timeit-%~n1.bat -Wait}"
del ~timeit-%~n1.bat
```

Then when you want to time the execution of something, say, `systeminfo`, just `timeit systeminfo`.

---

If you prefer a non-powershell solution (as powershell takes several annoying seconds to prime itself in its first run per Windows session), here's a faster batch / JScript hybrid solution ([more info](https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/5199433)).  It also executes the command in the same window, whereas the powershell solution spawns a new window for your command.  Save this as `timer.bat`:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end   /*  begin multiline JScript comment

:: timer.bat command args
:: measures execution time of a command
@echo off & setlocal

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Usage: %~nx0 command args
    goto :EOF
)
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" %*
goto :EOF

:: end batch portion / begin JScript */
var osh = new ActiveXObject('wscript.shell'), cmd = [], b4 = new Date();

for (var i=0; i<WSH.Arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = WSH.Arguments(i);
    cmd.push(/\s/.test(arg) ? '"' + arg + '"' : arg);
}

var exe = osh.Exec('cmd /c ' + cmd.join(' '));
while(!exe.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) WSH.Echo(exe.StdOut.ReadLine())

var x = (new Date() - b4) / 1000,
    d = Math.floor(x / 86400),
    d = d ? d + ' days ' : '',
    h = ('0' + (Math.floor(x / 3600) % 24)).slice(-2),
    m = ('0' + (Math.floor(x / 60) % 60)).slice(-2),
    s = Math.floor(x % 60) + x % 1,
    s = (s < 10) ? '0'+s : s;

WSH.Echo('\r\nExecution completed in ' + d + h + ':' + m + ':' + s);
```